# basic neo4j invisible characters in neo4j_sh

Tags: shell, neo4j

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm new to neo4j and when I try to write commands in the neo4j-sh shell the characters are all invisible.
I have created a database following other tutorials.
I start the shell and point it to the database directory:

```
neo4j-shell -path ../database
```

and I am presented with:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$
```

however when I try to type commands:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ > > > SyntaxException: expected either node or relationship here
"start node = n"
```

As you can see no characters are not displayed when I type commands. I only get a '>' after each return.

successful quesries are returned and displayed.

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ > +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[0]{}                                                       |
| Node[1]{name:"Leisure"}                                         |
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a hickup after your wrong syntax. can you try restarting the shell?

Comment: I have tried restarting the shell, restarting the neo4j service and rebooting my machine. The problem still persists despite this.

Comment: Does the user running neo4j-shell have permission to write to the directory where you launched the shell from? I wonder if it's related to this -> http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/11/29/neo4j-the-case-of-windows-neo4j-desktop-and-the-invisible-text/